# what does ignore function do in SML

Tags: list, sml

what does ignore function do in SML

```
fun prntlst f l =
      if NULL l then ()
      else (ignore(f (HD l)); prntlst f (TL(l)));
```

what does ignore do here

Answer (score 2):

The `ignore` function does nothing. It simply ignores its argument and returns `()`.

The point of the function is to avoid warnings about a return value not being used. That is if you have a function `f` whose return type is not `unit`, then calling `f` without using the return value will cause a warning. If you wrap `ignore` around it, it won't.